# Send data to components with Models

Tags: angular6, ng-bootstrap

HI im using Angular 6 with ng-boostrap.
how can i send data to the component while opening the PopUP?
this actually popup inside popup.

call stacked models

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

```
popUPOrders() {
this.modalService.open(OrdersComponent, {
  size: 'lg'
});
```

the only way to open the POPUP is to use modelSerivce.open and there is no fields to attach data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to send like this

```
 popUPOrders() {
const modelRef = this.modalService.open(OrdersComponent, { size: 'lg' })
modelRef.componentInstance.obj = this.customerObj;}
```

And create variables in OrdersComponent

```
obj:any;
```

Answer (score 0):

The data to be passed needs to be input properties on the content component.In your case add Input properties for the OrdersComponent component.
Link:  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples
Bootstrap site example(Component as content):

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-component',
  templateUrl: './modal-component.html'
})
export class NgbdModalComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }
}
```